# Is it illegal for a business to ask for proof that an animal is a service animal?

Tags: customer-service, animals, tennessee

I work for a hotel in Tennessee. I know it's illegal to refuse service to a guest with a service animal, despite not being a pet-friendly hotel, but I've been told that it's illegal to even *ask* for proof that a guest's animal is a service animal.

Is there any truth to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot ask for proof/documentation. According to the [U.S. Department of Justice](https://www.ada.gov/regs2010/service_animal_qa.html):

> In situations where it is not obvious that the dog is a service animal, staff may ask only two specific questions: (1) is the dog a service animal required because of a disability? and (2) what work or task has the dog been trained to perform? Staff are not allowed to request any documentation for the dog, require that the dog demonstrate its task, or inquire about the nature of the person's disability.

Comment: What are the consequences if the customer lies? "We spent $1,000 on fully cleaning your room for your non-service "service" dog".